# What determines if a quasiparticle is a spinon or a vison?

Tags: topological-order, anyons, quasiparticles

Across topological literature, I've seen references to spinons and visons. In Kitaev's famous "Anyons in an exactly solved model" paper, he mentions that visons are "spinless bosons" whereas spinons can be fermionic and bosonic.

It is known that anyons can hold fractionalized values under symmetries. Is the quasiparticle "spin" that determines the spinon/vison classification the same "spin" that arises from fractionalization of rotational symmetry? If that is the case, then why do many discussions of fractionalization start with the assumption that the anyon spinon/vison classification is already known? i.e. why is the rotation fractionalization given special treatment?

Comment: What is in a name? As far as I understand, any excitation with $S=\frac{1}{2}$ quantum number can be (and, usually, is) called a spinon. So no assumptions are made, it's rather just a definition. But if this comment misses your point, perhaps you can attempt to rephrase your question?